# Gensim error when importing Word2Vec model

Tags: python, gensim, word2vec

I'm trying to import a downloaded model from Google. I'm doing this using the following code:

```
import gensim

model= gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('C://gensim/model/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz', binary=True)
```

However, when run, I get this error:

```
File "C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site packages\smart_open\smart_open_lib.py", line 309, in __init__
raise NotImplementedError("unknown URI scheme %r in %r" % (self.scheme, uri))
NotImplementedError: unknown URI scheme 'c' in 'C://gensim/model/GoogleNews-vectors-negative300.bin.gz'
```

The file path is correct, and name for the model, however I cannot get it to import correctly. I have been using [this](http://mccormickml.com/2016/04/12/googles-pretrained-word2vec-model-in-python/) guide.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be an issue with your path parameter.

You should use backslashes (`\`) instead of slashes for your path.

Alternatively you can use the `os.path` module to build a path independently of the platform.

Finally, you could use a relative path instead. For example, put your file in the folder when you run your python program and use `'./filename.bin.gz'` as a parameter.

For more info, [this article](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%e2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/) details the use of slashes and backslashes in python.